# How to return a value from a shell script in a python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a python script which requires a value from a shell script.

Following is the shell script (a.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
return_value(){
  value=$(///some unix command)
  echo "$value"
}

return_value
```

Following is the python script:

```
Import subprocess
answer = Subprocess.call([‘./a.sh’])
print("the answer is %s % answer")
```

But its not working.The error is "ImportError : No module named subprocess ". I guess my verison (Python 2.3.4) is pretty old. Is there any substitute for subprocess that can be applied in this case??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `subprocess.check_output`:

```
import subprocess
answer = subprocess.check_output(['./a.sh'])
print("the answer is {}".format(answer))
```

help on `subprocess.check_output`:

```
>>> print subprocess.check_output.__doc__
Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.
```

Demo:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> answer = subprocess.check_output(['./a.sh'])
>>> answer
'Hello World!\n'
>>> print("the answer is {}".format(answer))
the answer is Hello World!
```

`a.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
STR="Hello World!"
echo $STR
```

Comment: thanks ashwini for the answer.. The statement inside the python script is not actually a print statment but a cvs command. I had simplified it just for the sake of asking. So in that case can we use {} for interpolating the answer variable or we need to use %s ???

Comment: @user2475677 [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) is called new-style string formatting, if you're using string formatting only then both options are fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot ashwini, but I just realised that , my version of Python (2.3.4) is pretty old!! It does not have "subprocess"

Comment: What if this "a.sh" script is an interactive script which prompts user few question. In that case how can we capture those values in python script...?

Answer (score 3):

use **Subprocess.check_output** instead of  **Subprocess.call**.

**Subprocess.call** returns return code of that script. 

**Subprocess.check_output** returns byte stream of script output.

[Subprocess.check_output on python 3.3 doc site](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)