# Compare 2 images and find % difference

Tags: python, image, difference

I want to compare two images and know the % difference between them. I am using raspbian on raspberry pi and python language. I have found PIL and magickimage, but with magick image I can't find a function for this and with PIL I have strange results.

For Pil i use this code :

```
h1 = image1.histogram()
h2 = image2.histogram()
rms = math.sqrt(reduce(operator.add,map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2, h1, h2))/len(h1))
```

When i take two pics ( no difference ) with 0.5 seconds of intervall i have this results : rms = 4743.766.... If i move during between the two pics i have rms : 4699.288..... 
So it's does not make the difference between the two " sames " images and when i move :/

Comment: What, precisely, does *"strange results"* mean? Where's the code, and what exactly is the problem with it/

Comment: I edited it :)
Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `compare` which is part of ImageMagick. Like this:

```
compare -metric AE image1.png image2.png null:
```

The `AE` gives the absolute error, in terms of  a count of the number of pixels difference. You can also use `MAE` (mean absolute error), or `PAE` (peak absolute error) or `RMSE` (root mean square error). You can also add a `fuzz` factor to allow slight differences in pixel values like this:

```
compare -fuzz 10% -metric AE image1.png image2.png null:
```

If you want the answer in a shell variable, say `ndiff`, you can do this:

```
ndiff=`compare -fuzz 10% -metric AE image1.png image2.png null: `
echo $ndiff
```

Comment: I am very bad in linux. In the console it's ok, it's gave ne a value but i don't know how write it in my script. I have try that :
    diff=compare -metric AE image1.png image2.png null
    print(diff)
But he said that there is an error on the "AE"
It's strange because it's works well in the console. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I'll update the answer... hold on.

Comment: It's seems invalid syntax on the $. So the script couldn't be executed :/

Comment: If you are using an older, or non-bash shell, you may have to use backticks instead - see updated answer.

Comment: I am not really sure to understand. When i do it in my console it's works. But i want to do it in my python file, no. And i have try all the code you gave but when i do : python scr.py it does not works because of the code above. Maybe i have forget to import something to use the function compare ?

And i am using a raspberry pi with raspbian with the system on date.

Comment: If you want the answer (i.e. difference) in a Python variable, have a look at the answer to this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238263/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-shell-script-in-a-python-script