# Call shell script from python code without any return value (0) or new lines

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell

Let's say my shell script returns a value of '19' when it is run. I'd like to store that value (without any return value of 0 or empty lines) into a variable in my python code for use later.

There are many questions here with similar reference to mine but I have yet to find a solution where the shell script is returning me '19' without a extra return value of 0 or new lines.

Using `subprocess.call('bash TestingCode', shell=True)` in the python code returns me exactly what I want however when I store this command in a variable and then print the variable, it prints with an extra 0.

```
answer = subprocess.call('bash TestingCode', shell=True)
print answer
```

`>>19`
`>>0`

I then tried an example from this question: [How to return a value from a shell script in a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238263/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-shell-script-in-a-python-script)

However it returns me an extra empty line instead.

```
answer = subprocess.check_output('bash TestingCode', shell=True)
print answer
>>19
>>
```

I really appreciate the help!

UPDATE: *TestingCode script*

```
#!/bin/bash
num=19
echo $num
```

Comment: you get `19`on the screen because bash script runs `print(19)` (or something similar). It doesn't return `19` and you can't assign it to variable. If script runs `exit(19)` (or something similar) then you get this value in variable `answer`

Comment: Can you share your shell script

Comment: @AlokThakur my shell script is simply `num=19` `echo $num`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it like this:

```
import subprocess

answer = subprocess.check_output('bash TestingCode', shell=True)
answer = answer.rstrip()
```

The reason is that your shell script is printing `19` followed by a new line. The return value from `subprocess.check_output()` will therefore include the new line produced by the shell script. Calling `str.rstrip()` will remove any trailing whitespace, leaving just `'19'` in this case.

Comment: also, to clarify on when you say "the reason is that your shell script is printing 19 followed by a new line", my script (as updated on my question) prints just 19 when it is run on it own (outside the python code), so where would the extra line be coming from?

Comment: There is no "extra" new line, just the one that `echo` outputs by default. You can tell echo not to output the trailing new line with the `-n` option, i.e.  `echo -n $num` and then you don't need to use `rstrip()`, even though it usually doesn't hurt to strip the string.

Comment: It just like print in python2.x print with extra line, which allow line change. 
Similar behavior echo demonstrate. You can verify this by 
res = subprocess.Popen('script.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True);
res.communicate()

Comment: i have another small question which might be slightly off topic so please bear with me if you can > how can i get python to treat the variable 'answer' as an integer? or is that not possible in my case?

Comment: Just call `answer = int(answer)`. You don't even need to bother stripping the string anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling a `subprocess.Popen`, it returns without the 0.

Comment: this returns me an extra line `<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7eff60220550>` before showing the value 19

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I suspect you have a problem in your shell script that is causing the output.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
exit 19
(0) austin@Austins-Mac-8:~
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('bash test.sh', shell=True)
19
>>>
```

Comment: yep, as i mentioned in my question, when i call `subprocess.call('bash test.sh', shell=True)` directly, it returns me the current value, 19. it's only when i store it in a variable and then print the variable that it returns an extra "0"